# Unable to get the wrapper binance.net working

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, binance

I have installed the wrapper from https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net

Using their example code, I have the following in my app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Binance.Net;
using Binance.Net.Enums;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using Binance.Net.Objects.Spot;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Authentication;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Logging;

namespace binance_stream_user_data_updates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions{
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials("key","secret"),
                BaseAddress = "https://testnet.binance.vision",
                LogVerbosity = LogVerbosity.Debug,
                LogWriters = new List<TextWriter> { Console.Out }
            });

            var startResult = client.Spot.UserStream.StartUserStream();

            if(!startResult.Success)
                throw new Exception($"Failed to start user stream: {startResult.Error}");

            var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient();

            socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToUserDataUpdates(startResult.Data,
            null,
            data => {
                Console.WriteLine(data.Orders);
                },
            null,
            null);

            Console.ReadLine();

            socketClient.UnsubscribeAll();


        }
    }
}
```

I then run the above app which seems to connect and starts waiting, as the following is shown in the terminal:

```
dotnet run
2021/02/26 20:36:51:863 | Binance    | Debug | Client configuration: LogVerbosity: Debug, Writers: 1, Credentials: Set, BaseAddress: https://testnet.binance.vision/, Proxy: -, RateLimiters: 0, RateLimitBehaviour: Wait, RequestTimeout: 00:00:30
2021/02/26 20:36:51:903 | Binance    | Debug | [1] Creating request for https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/time
2021/02/26 20:36:51:911 | Binance    | Debug | [1] Sending GET request to https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/time 
2021/02/26 20:36:53:242 | Binance    | Debug | [1] Response received in 1320ms: {"serverTime":1614371813101}
2021/02/26 20:36:53:345 | Binance    | Debug | [2] Creating request for https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/time
2021/02/26 20:36:53:346 | Binance    | Debug | [2] Sending GET request to https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/time 
2021/02/26 20:36:54:028 | Binance    | Debug | [2] Response received in 681ms: {"serverTime":1614371813881}
2021/02/26 20:36:54:029 | Binance    | Info | Time offset set to 535.073ms
2021/02/26 20:36:54:031 | Binance    | Debug | [3] Creating request for https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v1/userDataStream
2021/02/26 20:36:54:037 | Binance    | Debug | [3] Sending POST request to https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v1/userDataStream with request body 
2021/02/26 20:36:54:732 | Binance    | Debug | [3] Response received in 694ms: {"listenKey":"key"}
```

I then post an order

POST https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order?symbol=BNBUSDT&side=SELL&type=MARKET&quantity=0.1&newClientOrderId=my_order_id_201&newOrderRespType=FULL&timestamp=1614370483356&signature=58cfd86cffc626703eac32f14bf0fa2e9af4850fb33974a03d1eee3f666df15f

When I do that, the websocket running from the above code outputs nothing.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are things, that have to be done to get a proper result:

1. You have to specify options for `BinanceSocketClient`
2. You have to wait for some event before unsubscribing
3. While waiting you have to add new order (or new OCO order) using the Postman application (or other similar) with your credentials. (This is not covered by the code below)

Please have a look to the following code:

```
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions
    {
        ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials("key", "secret"),
        BaseAddress = "https://testnet.binance.vision",
        LogVerbosity = LogVerbosity.Debug,
        LogWriters = new List<TextWriter> { Console.Out }
    });

    var startResult = client.Spot.UserStream.StartUserStream();

    if (!startResult.Success)
        throw new Exception($"Failed to start user stream: {startResult.Error}");

    var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions
    {
        ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials("key", "secret"),
        BaseAddress = "wss://testnet.binance.vision",
        LogVerbosity = LogVerbosity.Debug,
        LogWriters = new List<TextWriter> { Console.Out }
    });

    var stop = false;
    var subscribeResponse = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToUserDataUpdates(
        startResult.Data,
        data =>
        {
            stop = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"Order updated: {data}");
        },
        data =>
        {
            stop = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"OCO Orders updated: {data.Orders}");
        },
        null,
        data =>
        {
            stop = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"Balance updated: ${data}");
        });
    
    if (subscribeResponse.Success)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }

    await socketClient.UnsubscribeAll();
}
```

Comment: I am using .NET 3.1.  It seems 'Task' does not exist until .NET 4.  Made some adjustments to your example code and it is now working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `socketClient` is unsubscribed from events immediately after subscribing.

You need to swap the lines

```
socketClient.UnsubscribeAll();
Console.ReadLine();
```

to have a subscription to events until the line from the console is read.

Comment: Swapped the lines around and it doesn't seem to make a difference to the output when I post an order.

Comment: It looks like updates only come when the balance is changed. See [here](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/issues/560#issuecomment-773903979).

Comment: Yes, I change the balance using this command api endpoint "POST https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order?symbol=BNBUSDT&side=SELL&type=MARKET&quantity=0.1&newClientOrderId=my_order_id_201&newOrderRespType=FULL&timestamp=1614370483356&signature=58cfd86cffc626703eac32f14bf0fa2e9af4850fb33974a03d1eee3f666df15f"

I can see the balance change when I log into binance, but nothing is outputted from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code you create a `BinanceClient` with options using the testnet URL, and then you create a `BinanceSocketClient` with default options that will use `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/` as the base URL.

But if you use the test network, then you have to use the corresponding `wss://testnet.binance.vision/` web socket URL; otherwise, you subscribe to a nonfunctional listenKey in the real network, which will not inform you about the order updates that happen in the test network.

Just create the `BinanceSocketClient` instance like this:

```
socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions
{
    BaseAddress = "wss://testnet.binance.vision",
    LogWriters = new List<TextWriter> { Console.Out }
});
```